# How to trigger "hide" a row in Conditional Formatting/ Custom Rule

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to remove (hide) a row from view if certain condition hits. How can this be accomplished, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var condition = true;
  if (condition) sheet.hideRow(sheet.getRange("A1"));
}
```

Comment: Yuri, thank you. How would I trigger script execution if certain conditions hit? Ideally I would like to call it from conditional formatting. THANK YOU

Comment: I can only confirm the words of @doubleunary. To run a script you need to change something on the sheet manually. And then you can use trigger `onEdit()` which can check out any cells for any conditions and hide any rows.

Answer (score 2):

Google Sheets does not support hiding *rows* using a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) rule. What you can do is to hide *values* by using conditional formatting to set the text color of their cells to white (or whatever the cell fill color happens to be).

To hide *rows*, you will need a script. You may want to look into an `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that runs automatically when you *hand edit* the spreadsheet.